# MkDocs-with-pdf admonition icons on wrong position in pdf

Tags: html, markdown, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I would like to write a manual that is output as both an html and a pdf file. I am working with MkDocs material and the plugin mkdocs-with-pdf. This works very well for everything I have in mind, but the icons of the admonitions in the pdf file are in the wrong place, in the html file everything is okey.

[in pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX025.png)
[in html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB33h.png)

I tried to force the icons to the left side with an extra.css, but that didn't work.

extra.css:

```
.admonition-icon {
    float: left; 
    margin-right: 3px; 
}
```

.md file:

```
<div class="admonition warning">
<p class="admonition-title">Caution</p>
<p>Insert text here</p>
</div>
```

Can I possibly do this in my .md file, or do you have any other ideas? I may have written my extra.css incorrectly.

I hope for help :)